# Plotly groupby transforms

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I plot multiple box traces automatically by grouping like below:

```
  const fcbox = {
    y: values,
    type: "box",
    showlegend: false,
    transforms: [
      {
        type: "groupby",
        groups: gvalues
      }
    ]
  };
```

The values in `gvalues` are numeric. I was expecting the boxes are ordered and placed in the `x-axis` using their *numerical* value. But, they are treated as if they are *categorical*.

However, If I had not used the transform and manually grouped and created the many box traces myself (with name set to the numerical value) and supplied them as data to the plot, it would place them nicely on the `x-axis` based on their *numerical* value. How can I get it working with the groupby transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I'm understanding your question correctly, but I think this "just works" unless there's something else in your figure that's changing the defaults.

This code:

```
Plotly.newPlot(
  "gd",
  [{
    type: "box",
    x: [1,1,1,2,2,2,7,7,7],
    y: [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
    transforms: [
      {
        type: "groupby",
        groups: [1,1,1,2,2,2,7,7,7]
      }]
  }],
  {}
);
```

yields this output:

[image]